# Why can't I get this header - built w/Thrive Architect - to go full-width?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to get the black header on this page - http://radionowheremusic.com/ - to span the entire width of the browser window, but can't quite figure out how to target it with CSS. Thrive Architect has created a bunch of DIVs in this area and I can't find the one that actually contains the black header.

Apologies if this is unclear, but I'm pretty confused. Let me know if there's any other info I can provide which might help clear this up.

P.S. I tried absolute positioning for this div; that worked, but affected other elements further down the page as well, so obviously my targeting didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the element you're trying to to make full-width is contained within several different elements that aren't full-width themselves.

The best way would be to refactor the markup, but if you're not able to do that there are some CSS tricks you could do. https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

This one works when applied to the element div.thrv_wrapper element that contains the header.

```
div.thrv_wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

The problem you're going to run into is finding a class that is specific enough to target to only effect the header. Since it looks like `.thrv_wrapper` is used throughout.

You could try targeting it specifically using the `:first-child` psuedo element. Something like this should work, but I can't be certain it will across your entire theme `.entry-content #tve_editor > .thrv_wrapper:first-child`.

So your final CSS could look like:

```
.entry-content #tve_editor > .thrv_wrapper:first-child {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

Not the prettiest selector, but it should get the job done.

Comment: This solution does shift things around a little, but still doesn't seem to give me the full-width header I'm looking for - http://radionowheremusic.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just after the body tag, there is a div id='page' tag.  remove all the padding css and the black bar will span the entire browser window

Comment: Hmmm...tried adjusting the padding  for the page div, but it doesn't seem to have the effect I'm looking for...